# Cannot use 'in' operator to search for 'X' in undefined

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuetify.js, vuex

**Uncaught TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for 'USERS' in undefined** I can't understand this line : `use 'in' operator to search for 'USERS'`
and also why `undefined` ?

I do not understand these errors please explain to me.

**My Vuex** :

```
 export default new Vuex.Store({
  state: {
    users: []
  },

  actions: {
    GET_USERS_FROM_API({commit})  {
      return axios('http://localhost:3000/users', {
        method: GET
      })
      .then((response) => {
        commit('SET_USERS_TO_VUEX', response.data)
      })
    }
    
  },
  mutations: {
    SET_USERS_TO_VUEX: (state, users) => {
      state.users = users
    }
  },
  getters: {
        USERS(state) {
      return state.users
    }
},

  modules: {

}
```

**Here is my script:**

```
import {mapActions, mapGetters} from 'vuex'
export default {
  name: 'Home',
  components: {
  },
  data() {

  },

  computed: {
    ...mapGetters([
      'USERS'
    ])

  },

  methods: {
    ...mapActions([
      'GET_USERS_FROM_API'
    ])
  },

  mounted() {
    this.GET_USERS_FROM_API()
  }
}

</script>
```

Maybe I misstaked in `axios` response in my `vuex` ? I `defined` users in state. I think i get error in my `axios` response, but I do not know how to fix it.

Comment: Maybe unrelated but `method: GET` should be `method: 'GET'`

Comment: in my code method 'GET'

Comment: The error refers to the `in` operator which isn't used in your post, so maybe it's coming from somewhere else.   https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Errors/in_operator_no_object

Answer (score 3):

syntax error, forgot to put quotation marks to the GET method and also forgot to import axios

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you forgot ro return object in your data statement and vue crashes.

The valid data property is :

```
data() {
   return{};
  },
```